# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': CONNECT tunnel failed, response 421

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

i tried to clone my github reporsitory into my vs code, but i always got this error. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git instance has been configured to use a proxy and that proxy is failing.

Try unsetting the environment variables, for example on Linux:

```
export http_proxy=
export https_proxy=
export HTTP_PROXY=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
```

Check your git config files for a proxy. Unset them with these commands:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --unset http.proxy
git config --unset https.proxy
```

Check the vscode interface for these options (environment variables and proxy settings). Try changing the proxy options from system to none.